# Import and Concatenate wave files

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, wav, eclipse-neon

If something this specific/simple has already been answered, I'm really sorry,, I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem I'm having.

Currently, I'm trying to code a program for my Senior Independent Study of Programming Language class that involves a *lot* of .wav files. I'm using Eclipse Neon, and I'm working in Java. My issue, currently, is properly importing .wav files, and then the proper way to concatenate several together.

Here's the code of the class that utilizes these files. Feel free to critique my methods here, I'm at a total loss.

```
private ArrayList<String> paths;

public audioGen(){
    paths = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public ArrayList<String> formList(int l, String type) {
    Random a = new Random();
    int b;
    if(type.equals("A")){
            for(int x=0; x<l;x++){
                b = a.nextInt(14);
                paths.add("/res/"+Integer.toString(b)+".wav");
            }
    }
    return paths;
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")

public void soundAppend(ArrayList<String> pathList) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        AudioInputStream clip1 = null;
        for(String path1 : pathList){
            if (clip1 == null){
                clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File (path1));
                continue;
            }
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path1));
            AudioInputStream appendFiles = new AudioInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2), clip1.getFormat(), clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());
            clip1 = appendFiles;
        }
    AudioSystem.write(clip1, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("src\\audio\\completed.wav"));
    clip1.close();
}

public void readList(ArrayList<String> l){
    for(String s : l)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

I have the folders set so that /res/ is a build path under the package AUDIOWORK, and the source files under com/rade/gen/. Is it an issue of them not being close enough to access, or do I need to create audioInputStreams to use them; if that's the case, how would I concatenate them from there.

Thank you so much in advanced, and sorry again if this was answered somewhere else. I've spent two weeks trying to figure out how this works to no avail. :/

*EDIT: I want to specify that this is a rewrite of a project I rushed nearly 3 years ago, so there are a lot of things in it that I'm not currently refreshed on - specifically the code for the `soundAppend` method.*

Comment: You are creating an `AudioInputStream` by creating `SequenceInputStream`. So what exactly seems to be a problem? Are you asking if this is the right way to do it? Does it work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Yeah, the exception it spits out every time is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/0.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: That path is mentioned in `formList` and you don't show how that is used. But isn't the error message clear enough? The file doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a file 0.wav in your /res/0.wav folder? Assuming you are using *nix, that would be from your root, not relative...

Comment: the pathList implementation has to do with another class - it's awkward and clumsy, but I'm still working on it.
Regardless, the file does exist. I made it myself. The problem is I'm not entirely sure how to direct java to the right location without giving it the full, explicit path. All this is mostly for the goal of packaging it later as an executable of some form to be run elsewhere on other computers.

Comment: @bc004346 can you clarify what you mean by *nix? I'm unfamiliar with that term. And by root do you mean C:\ or the root of the project/package

Edit: 0.wav does exist in that directory (~\AUDIOWORK\res\0.wav), but the whole point is for any one of the 14 wav files to be called - I put 0 as a placeholder.

Comment: The problem is with the file path - it obviously does not find anything... see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in getting the right path to your file. Since you mentioned that you already added your resource folder to the classpath, this should work:

```
public ArrayList<String> formList(int l, String type) {
    Random a = new Random();
    int b;
    if(type.equals("A")){
        for(int x=0; x<l;x++){
            b = a.nextInt(14);
            Url url = this.getClass().getResource(Integer.toString(b)+".wav");
            paths.add(url.toString());
        }
    }
    return paths;
}
```

Comment: That actually is very useful, but unfortunately it causes a further exception - `getResource()` returns a URL for the X.wav file, of which the ArrayList `pathList` is not. I considered making `pathList` an ArrayList<URL> instead of String, but as I was researching the viability of this I saw that the File objects can't easily be constructed using URL objects. Ideas for course of action?

Comment: Try this: `this.getClass().getResource(Integer.toString(b)+".wav").toString()`

Comment: That was actually my first inclination - however then it gave the following exception:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.rade.gen.audioGen.formList(audioGen.java:21)
        at com.rade.gen.Main.init(Main.java:30)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
`
Which I'm having a hard time processing

Comment: @DadeRobison So you need to break it down a bit probably. I have no way of knowing which line is line 21 in your source code. Try my edit